# How can I modify Boost UDP Unicast receive code so it also receives Broadcast datagrams?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, broadcast

How do I amend (the following) code that receives UDP Unicast messages, to also receive UDP Broadcast messages?
I have some Linux embedded code using Boost ASIO that receives messages (paraphrased code)

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd","12345"));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor.listen();
    acceptor.async_accept(socket, bind(handler,...))
    ..
    // udp server 
    udp_socket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(io_service, udp_endpoint);
    udp_socket->async_receive_from(bind(readhandler,...),...)
```

This works well. However, I don't know what additions/alterations I need to do for the code to also receive messages that were sent by *broadcast* to this server (the network) (i.e., to "aaa.bbb.255.255").

I have tried creating a second bc_endpoint (aaa.bbb.255.255) but the acceptor will not bind to more than one endpoint.  I am basically trying to avoid replicating **all** the Unicast code, but perhaps that is inevitable?

I have also tried creating a second socket "udp_socket_bc" for the broadcast address, but that doesn't seem to trigger any incoming messages.

```
    boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver udp_resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::query udp_query("aaa.bbb.255.255", "12345"));
    udp_socket_bc = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(io_service, udp_endpoint_bc);
    udp_socket_bc->async_receive_from(bind(readhandler_bc, ...), ...)
```

I have opened the embedded system for incoming traffic:

```
    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

My code doesn't react to incoming messages if they were sent to the broadcast address, but I can tell (using tcpdump) that the embedded system is actually seeing them. What is a good way to change UDP Unicast code to also receive UDP Broadcast messages?

Comment: Just bind to 0.0.0.0, however that manifests itself in `boost::asio`. You don't have to do anything specific to receive broadcasts, only set SO_BROADCAST to enable sending them.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks!  I understand from what you're saying that if I am listening to a **specific** address (a.b.c.d) it will also automatically hear stuff sent to the subnet (a.b.255.255). Correct?  No other actions necessary, except maybe firewall/port rules?

Comment: Eh? I neither stated nor implied any such thing. If you want to ask whether that's true, by all means ask, but don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @user207421 You claim that I don't have to do anything specific to receive broadcasted messages. Now, the situation I have to relate to is that I already have code that works for unicast messages.  So I am asking you if I understood you correctly, by asking if I **should** be able to hear broadcasts to ip=a.b.255.255 when I'm listening to ip=a.b.c.d.  Because I obviously don't. Which implies that I am doing something else wrong, like perhaps some incorrect system setting.